# Multiple select is not working using bootstrap class="custom-select" multiple

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, html-select, multiple-select

I am trying to make it available that user select more than option:

```
<select class="custom-select" form-control" multiple>
    @foreach($permission_maps as $permission_map)
        <option value="">{{$permission_map}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Only one option could be selected
[image: selected items]

Comment: you have added an extra quote in class. change the 1st line to  `<select class="custom-select form-control" multiple  >`

Comment: thankd Anees, I changed it but still NOT working

Comment: What do you mean saying "not working"? You can not select field even with pressed ctrl or selected options are not visible in your controller (different $request->input())?

Comment: I found out that even one selection is not applied as if nothing selected because it gives:   The permissions field is required. !!!!

Comment: thanks Harven so much , it was solved by adding name attribute

Answer (score 0):

Change the select tag to this:

```
<select class="custom-select form-control" multiple>
```

Answer (score 0):

select name attribute should have the name of table column:

```
<select **name ="permissions[]"**  class="custom-select  form-control" multiple>
```

here column name is permissions

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="inputName[]" class="custom-select" form-control" multiple>
@foreach($permission_maps as $permission_map)
    <option value="">{{$permission_map}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```